# lightning Component access denied from namespace

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I am testing a simple lightning component which uses 3rd party js loaded as static resource. Originally I made in in a traiheadplayground. It is a sigle component and in app that only includes that component. I tested it there properly and then I tried same outside of the playgound - I got error:

```
Action failed: c:mycmp$controller$jsLoaded [Access denied: {"from":{"namespace":"c"}}]
```

Search showed that problem is the lockerservice, so I switched API version to 39 (both app and component) and tried again - no luck. Then I was trying different combinations of api version and my code. And eventually I got to the point when the app was in the initial state (same resource, api version 42, all of my code enabled as initially) and it just worked!

I was baffled, I uploaded same static resource under different name, used it in component - exception appeared. So now there are 3 states I am testing:

```
// works
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.myres + '/cmp.min.css'}"
              scripts="{!$Resource.myres + '/cmp.js'}"
// throws access denied error
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.myres1 + '/cmp.min.css'}"
              scripts="{!$Resource.myres1 + '/cmp.js'}"
// throws access error too, from js code!
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.myres1 + '/cmp.min.css'}"
              scripts="{!$Resource.myres + '/cmp.js'}"
```

resources are identical - I uploaded it twice with different names. static resource tab shows size is equal. but one doesn't work.

I have a feeling that API version is not updated instantly and maybe even somehow cached for resource/cmp combination?
Has anyone experienced this before? What could I try understand this issue?

Comment: This is bit funny. Are you on Summer 18?

Comment: I am using trial and haven't specified any version. I am using default I guess, not sure what is it.